# What is CLR loop optimization behavior?

Tags: c#, loops, clr

I was wondering that if I iterate over an array with foreach the JITter later will replace the foreach loop with simple for-loop to drop enumerator penalty, is this true? and if it is, what about `List`? because list is backed with an array.

And finally what is the optimizations on Linq, consider following:

```
var result = typeof(List<int>).GetInterfaces()
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType);
```

Will this get any optimizations?

Comment: The compiler used on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoRLUAsW2OcAzCgExIDCSOA3jkiyhQJYB2wSAsqgAouwANoBdJGABOUgJT1srJE0WsAkMMkBjLUgC8SBMSVLmJlgDMA9lKRDuSdvsPpHSADySZAOgAyAU04Ac2AAC1d2AGpI2TNzFXNzMB0kSINpKRF2MWNEgF84k0KlOAB2bS1clgKSVRZyRwdeSntRCQz5QoT1TWTdAyNi1iHLG39k0LtNADdGrzkR5UWlPtSDaaqTGsSFHbKKzZrChs1eMgFfdghgd2EAPnnOuqXnjQdVgc3TZ6VrKXGtJNWkhZlxHotujsWKs0iCvqxtolFvs+occMcOE0CAI0GRbtwHh1dqxIUg3jwPi5Fos/gCgTM5h0IctWDD1vDqtSfqwUTo0dg8kA=) (C# 2.8.2, quite new) doesn't optimize `List<>` enumeration (see right pane, M3)

Comment: No.  Iterators require a call to the IEnumerable<>.MoveNext() interface method.  At just-in-time compile time, the jitter does not yet know which specific object implements this interface, that doesn't get sorted out until the method is actually called.  So it cannot inline the method nor make any assumptions about how it behaves.  You pay for the CALL, plus a single JMP in the stub that binds to the actual method in the concrete type.  Very fast, you'd need a simple collection element type to see that overhead.

Comment: @HansPassant By wholly inlining the `FirstOrDefault()` it could be optimized: `GetInterfaces()` returns a `Type[]` so an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On C# 2.8.2 (it should be the latest as 25 July 2018) on .NET 4.7.2650:

- the `for` and `foreach` on an array are fully optimized, and
- the `for` on a `List<T>` is fully optimized by inlining the code of `.Count` and the indexer `[]`.

You can see it on [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), right pane: the methods `ArrayFor`, `ArrayForEach` and `ListFor` don't call external methods (but `ListFor` has the code to call the `ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException` method, that is the call made by the indexer `[]`). `ListForEach` has calls to ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1+Enumerator[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].MoveNext() ``` so it isn't wholly inlined. `EnumerableForEach` doesn't have explicit calls where you can see method names because by using an interface it can use directy the addresses of the methods (see the various `call dword [0x218a0084]`, `call dword [0x218a0088]`...)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,

- You can be sure that `foreach` on the array **will** be optimized away
- Foreach on the `List<T>` **won't** be optimized
- Iterating over `IEnumerable<T>` and linq **won't** be optimized

But optimizations depends much on the compiler and its version, so the best approach is to play around with your compiler and check IL code on simple cases.

[Useful article from 2014](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/844781/Digging-Into-NET-Loop-Performance-Bounds-checking)

Comment: Actually Linq does optimize based on the actually type of the `IEnumerable<T>` for some methods, but that's specifically done in code and not via compiler optimizations.